# Passing Viewbag object to controller through ajax in mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which passes an object to view to display in table.

```
student result = new student("dss");
ViewBag.result = result;
```

And view1 displays the student details with checkbox

```
 <table>
 @foreach (student detail in ViewBag.result.Get_student_details)
{
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="reprocess_data" value=@detail />
</td>}
<td>@detail.name</td>
<td>@detail.id</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

view1 has a button and when this button is clicked i need to display a table with selected student indicated by checkbox.

```
function reprocess1() {
var yourArray = [];
$("input:checkbox[name=reprocess_data]:checked").each(function () {
    yourArray.push($(this).val());
});
if (yourArray.length==0) {
    alert("No selection made!");
}
else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'IDOC',
            data: { idoc: yourArray },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tableData").html(data);
                $("#tableData").fadeIn(1000);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
}
```

}

my problem here is passing it to controller back through ajax.
Student object isn't passed and converted to string.
Any suggestion on hw to handle this?

Comment: `data:  JSON.stringify({ idoc: yourArray }),`

Comment: i'm not able to get data in jquery itself

Comment: one issue i see is the brackets on your foreach loop.  you're including the <tr> opening tag, but not the closing tag in each loop.  that probably results in invalid html.

Comment: also, how is reprocess1 called?

Comment: here is a proof of concept:  https://jsfiddle.net/wczdjq9g/